# Format and Sort date and time in Python

Tags: python, sorting, date, time, format

I imported csv file to Python and it looks like

```
ric       date           time       price
VOD   01-AUG-2013     8:08:53.241    156
VOD   03-JAN-2013     8:25:43.241    129
VOD   07-MAR-2013     8:03:31.241    128
VOD   18-AUG-2013     8:18:53.241    120
...     ...              ...         ...
```

I need to sort this file by `date` and then by `time` from the oldest to newest.
However, I have to format the `date` and `time` first. But I am not sure how to do that. I tired to format `date` first, but it did work out.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

path = 'C:\\sample.csv'

data= pd.read_csv(path)
sorted(data, key=lambda each_dict: datetime.strptime(each_dict['date'], '%d-%b-%y'))
```

Can someone help me to format and sort `date` and `time` ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use following formats for converting your dates and times to `datetime` object:

For time:

```
'%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

For date:

```
'%d-%b-%Y'
```

And use a tuple which its first item is date and second is time :

```
sorted(data,
       key=lambda each_dict: (datetime.strptime(each_dict['date'], '%d-%b-%Y'),
                              datetime.strptime(each_dict['time'], '%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I use your code, but system gave me `string indices must be integers, not str`. I am not quite sure whats that suppose to mean...

Answer (score 0):

try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), you'll love it:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=r'\s+')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
del df['time']
print(df.sort(['date'], ascending=[0]).to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 ric                    date  price
 VOD 2013-08-18 08:18:53.241    120
 VOD 2013-08-01 08:08:53.241    156
 VOD 2013-03-07 08:03:31.241    128
 VOD 2013-01-03 08:25:43.241    129
```